# What are the differences between jspdf's methods addHTML() and fromHTML()?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

What are the differences between jspdf's methods `addHTML()` and `fromHTML()`? [Documentation](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#addHTML) only has info for the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This issue on GitHub](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/1176) doesn't mention specific differences between the two but does say that they are separate plugins with similar goals.

[From the issue:](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/1176)

> ### Existing jsPDF plugins
>
> Hi, I've been working on a new [html2pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf) package that uses html2canvas + jsPDF to convert HTML content to PDF. I know there are already three existing jsPDF plugins for HTML: `addHTML`, `fromHTML`, and `html2pdf` (same name). I don't want to step on any toes - from what I can tell:
>
> - `fromHTML` is the oldest plugin and renders the HTML directly to PDF (which is great), but its support for complex HTML/CSS is lacking.
> - `addHTML` is newer (but now deprecated) and uses html2canvas/rasterizeHTML to create a canvas, then puts the image onto the PDF page. Current state is described at [#944](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/944).
> - `html2pdf`: I haven't found much info (apart from the [demo](https://cdn.rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/examples/html2pdf/showcase_supported_html.html)), but it looks like it renders directly to PDF like fromHTML, which again is great but runs the risk of poor HTML/CSS support.